# Can Selenium tests written in java be executed in Play

Tags: java, selenium, playframework, playframework-1.x

Is it possible to run Selenium tests written in Java in the Play1 framework?

The Play! framework supports Selenium tests in their tests runner but the documentation states that the tests have to come as "HTML tables".

Selenium on the other side supports Java APIs which is much more convenient and offers all the capabilities of the normal programming language.

However I did not find anything in the Play! documentation about running Selenium tests written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having used Play myself, it does seem to have standard Java [dependency integration](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2/dependency) for pulling libraries from a Maven repository. From what it says in the documentation, you could edit the `dependencies.yml` file, and add something like:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play 1.2
    - org.seleniumhq.selenium -> selenium-java 2.24.1
```

which would allow you to use Selenium's standard Java API.